# XMLHttpRequest response doesn't return Authorization header

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm trying to get authorization token from server by using XMLHttpRequest, but only some headers are returned (without Authorization header).
Server is working on localhost:8080 but client application is on localhost:3000 so I tried to configure CORS.

On server site I created a CorsConfigurationSource bean:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","DELETE","PUT"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization, X-Content-Type-Options, " +
            "X-XSS-Protection, Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires, X-Frame-Options, Content-Length, Date"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

and on client site I use XMLHttpRequest:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/login", true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader(
  "Content-Type",
  "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader(
  "Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
  "Authorization"
);
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
  console.log("RESPONSE HEADER : " + httpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders());
};
httpRequest.withCredentials = true;
httpRequest.send(userBody);
```

When I try to get all headers I only get some of them (like cache-control, content-length, expires, pragma) without Authorization header and other headers. What should I change to get all of them? Thank You for any help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoI6j.png)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this by setting exposed headers on server site:

```
configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization, X-Content-Type-Options, " +
                    "X-XSS-Protection, Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires, X-Frame-Options, Content-Length, Date"));
```